# Allow User#Show when not signed in. remember_token IS NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Solved: The Issue is calling current_user in the controller when no one is signed in and there is no current user it throws an error, thanks for the efforts/time.

I want people to be able to view profile pages in my app whether or not they have an account on my website. Currently I get the error:

SQL:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-05 05:08:50 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1

NoMethodError (undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in `show'
```

I thinks its trying to define a remember token when there isn't supposed to be one when someone isn't actually signed in.

User Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
End
```

Comment: on what line the error is occurring?

Comment: Its failing on the definition of microposts because @user is nil

Comment: Check if the user with that id is present in your database.

Comment: It does, I go to the user page fine when I'm logged in. The id param is not passing i don't know how to make it.

Comment: Oh.. all I can guess from your code is there may be some problem in your url to show action. Can you show the code of the link to users#show action?

Comment: Not sure what you need. When I type in the URL in the address bar to go to a user's page I get the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23952/discussion-between-sybaritemanoj-and-ayounesi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is current_user is nil and it was called in the controller when no one is signed in. The result is that it throws an error.

I added if signed_in? next to those particular lines that have current_user in them and now everything renders properly.

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find_by_foo` utility don't throw a "Record-not-found"-error, whereas the `find`-method does. When `find` gets a integer, it will find by Id, automatically.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
End
```

This will throw a RecordNotFound if there is no user with this id; resulting, in production, in a 404.

Edit: After seeing your updated code, it seems your problem lies in `current_user` helper method, not in User.find.

Comment: In that case, most likely your User#find method is overridden. What is the value in params[:id]? And what happens if you feed that into the console: `irb> User.find(1337)` ?

Comment: It works the user is there. Seems the error lies elsewhere I just posted the SQL error seems like it has to do with my remember token

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page]) if !@user.nil?
   @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
   End
```

It will avoid the error.

Comment: It's saying don't if user is nil? then i probably need this line somewhere